# How to use SQL to label each row based on certain criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to correctly label each row based on certain criteria. For example the data I have is like this:
Table Product

```
Group product_id product_name category
1      123        Egg          A
1      456        Egg          A
1      456        Milk         A
1      789        Milk         A
2      135        Apple        B
2.     137        Orange       B
2.     137        Banana       B
2.     139        Strawberry   B
3.     235        Egg          A
3.     237        Apple        B
3.     237        Egg          B
3.     239        Orange       B
3.     239        Egg          B
```

Since product egg can be found in more than 1 product IDs and milk can be found in more than 1 product IDs, 123,456 and 789 should be marked as A. Basically if a product name appears more than once in a group, then it is marked as A, otherwise B.

I was trying to use array functions and compare them, but it doesn't work for this scenario. For example,

```
select product_id,array_agg(product_name) as p1 from product
```

Then compare p1 with another array (p2) from the self inner join.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey Austin, this is the criteria 'Since product ID 123 Egg is found in product ID 456, product 123 is labeled as A. The same is true with product ID 789 Milk. Since product ID 456 has no product names the same as others (since it has two), it is unique and then labeled as B.' Does that make sense?

Comment: Duplicate product ID 456 is unique since it has two products whereas the other two products only has one which was contained by product ID 456.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: As I understand it, you pick one product_id and label its rows A. Then you look for another product_id that has no product name in common with the rows labeled A and label its rows A, too. You do this until there is no other product_id with no name in the set of A labeled rows. So you pick one unlabled product_id and label it B. You look for another  product_id that has no name in common with the B set and label it B, too. And so on. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The main purpose is to compare the product names, like you described, whether or not the product names match or contain each other. Product 123 and Product 789 are contained by product 456 so they are labeled as A and product 456 is not contained by anybody then it is labeled as B. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, so I was wrong. Then Austin got it right. All product_id that only occur in one row get A. All product_id that occur in more than one row get B. Is this correct? If not, and you are not able to describe the labeling rule exactly, then maybe more sample data would help. Ten more lines so we see where this is heading.

Comment: Okay. Suppose I have product ID 135 with name Apple, ID 137 with name Orange and Banana (2 different product names) and ID 139 with name Strawberry. All three product IDs should be labeled as B, since there is no overlap among them  whatsoever in terms of product names, regardless of how many rows each ID take.

Comment: @poppies could you please edit your question and extend the sample with more data? It would be much easier to follow

Comment: @dshelya I have done so. Thanks

Comment: There are two clashes, 'Egg' and 'Milk'. The solution you propose is to label rows #1 and #4 A. But labeling rows #2 and #3 A would be another solution just as good as the one you propose. Is this correct? Or must it be rows #1 and #4 for some specific reason I don't see?

Comment: In your example, if I added 123|Peach, would that be B, because there is no other peach, or A, because 123|Egg is labeled A?

Comment: If you add 123 with Peach that will make it B since now product 456 doesn't contain the same name of 123 anymore.

Comment: Okay, now I think I got it. This is all about product 456. You want some query for this particular number. All rows for another product that have the same name as some 456 row get A. All other rows including the 456 rows get B. Is that correct? This query would be very simple to write.

Comment: @poppies what if you add `123|Milk`? (there would be 2 groups of egg + milk with IDs: `456` and `123`). would all products receive `B` then?

Comment: @dshelya great question. and I've looked at the rules again and just realized I made a mistake in the sample data. Since Milk can be found in more than one product IDs and Egg can be found in more than one product IDs, 123, 456 and 789 all should be labeled as A.

Comment: I've added more sample data in.

Comment: Frankly, I still struggle to come up with a formal definition of your rules.. Could you please edit and clearly define when we do what without referencing a particular example ID/name?. Like “if 2 or more products share ID - it’s a group. if a product X does not form a group - it is labeled B. If a product X is found in a group Y - it receives label A” and so on. It’s a guessing game otherwise

Comment: Original question edited.

Comment: I have revised the sample data and criteria. Can someone take a look and help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `Case When` statement?

```
Case 
    when product_name = 'egg' and category = 'a' then label = 'egg1'
    when product_name = 'egg' and category = 'b' then label = 'egg2'
    else 'no label'
End
```

I am referencing this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82487/case-with-multiple-conditions for clarity. - J

Comment: `CASE` is usually an ***expression*** (that returns a single, atomic value - like `a+b` - *not* a statement)....

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need to figure out how to label the Category, and I don't know what will be the products. There are new products coming in each day. So case when isn't really going to help here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your requirement. You state *product name appears only once in a group, then it is marked as A, otherwise B.* However, the data you show contains the exact opposite. The following produces what you said you wanted, not the values you posted. It will be correct or exactly the reverse. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=13aadfb9a5b11c4db49cdc5a7d47c063))

```
-- if a product name appears only once in a group, then it is marked as A, otherwise B.
with prod_group (group_id, product_name, cnt) as 
     ( select group_id,  product_name, count(*) 
         from products 
        group by group_id, product_name
     )  -- select * from  prod_group ;
 update products p 
    set category = case when grp.cnt = 1 then 'A' else 'B' end 
   from prod_group grp
  where ( p.group_id, p.product_name) = ( grp.group_id, grp.product_name);
```

**How it works:**  The prod_group CTE simply counts the number of times a product name appears in a group. The main "query" then uses this result to `update` category. Contrary to to your statement *case isn't really going to help* the CASE expression is exactly what you need.

Note: GROUP is an extremely poor choice for a column name as it is both a Postgres (conditional) and a SQL Standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).